# Populating function names in Brownie traces

Tags: solidity, brownie

When I check the traces of a tx, there are a lot of non populated names, e.g **<UnknownContract>.0x095ea7b3**

It is unclear and hard to trace.

But I know **0x095ea7b3** is the standard erc20 "approve(address,uint256)", some of the unknown contracts are erc20 I call (WETH, USDC...).

Is there a way to give brownie a list of mappings *(address->contract name, hash->function name)* for Brownie to display and clarify the call_trace() output?